# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to start getting to grips with PHP and also PDO. As I am starting now, I hear that PDO is more beneficial, that is why I am not using the more popular mysqli.

I am having trouble getting data inserted into my db using PDO. I wanted to try and use prepared statements to minimize sql injection. I have tried many ways and keep hitting a brick wall.

I could do with some pointers please.

here is the error message.

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\test-search\insert_property.php on line 61
```

This is the relevant php code.

```
// Insert Property

// Include db 

include 'db_connect_pdo.php';
include 'defines.php';

try {

// create SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO property (pid, title, intro_en, description_en, bedrooms,
bathrooms, address, city, country, stype, ptype, price)
VALUES(:pid, :title, :intro_en, :description_en, :bedrooms, :bathrooms, :address,
:city, :country, :stype, :ptype, :price)";

// prepare the statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


// bind the parameters and execute the statement
$stmt->bindValue(':pid', $pid);

$stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);

$stmt->bindValue(':intro_en', $intro_en);

$stmt->bindValue(':description_', $description_en);

$stmt->bindValue(':bedrooms', $bedrooms);

$stmt->bindValue(':bathrooms', $bathrooms);

$stmt->bindValue(':address', $address);

$stmt->bindValue(':city', $city);

$stmt->bindValue(':country', $country);

$stmt->bindValue(':stype', $stype);

$stmt->bindValue(':ptype', $ptype);

$stmt->bindValue(':price', $price);



// execute the statement

$stmt->execute();

} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{ 
echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
$conn = null;
?>
</blockquote></code>
```

Not sure where it is going wrong, any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember that you can also do $stmt->execute(array('pid' => $pdi, 'title' => $title, 'intro_en'...)); instead of binding values one by one. You can also use question marks for, I'd say, less codding (but probably a little more confusing).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is this line:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':description_', $description_en);
```

Should be:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':description_en', $description_en);
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: :) it happens to the best of us.